# In a gallery, how do I make my portrait image larger so as to fill the full div while also keeping it centered?

Tags: css

I have read other answers and can't find an answer that works for me. I am trying to create an image gallery that is both responsive and takes different sized and orientated images i.e. some will be landscape, others will be portrait. I want it so that no matter its size or orientation it fills the size of the div and is centered within it.

Currently, the div is 250px height and width is 23% of the container. This was the best I could get it. Using this method the landscape images show fine but the portrait images have whitespace on either side of as it is not taking up the full div.

How can I get it so that no matter the size of the image it will fill the div **without** stretching it? I don't mind if the image is larger and gets cut off via overflow: hidden just as long as it fully covers the div.

EDIT: corrected the size of my stated image container width as I said it wrong.

Here is my code:

CSS

```css
.gallery-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.image-container {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 23%;
}

div.image-container:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
    height: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
HTML
   <div class="gallery-container">
    
    <div class="image-container">
           <a target="_blank" href="img/60.jpg">
               <img src="img/60.jpg" alt="flowers">
           </a>
           <!-- <div class="desc">Add a description here
                  
               </div> -->
    </div>
      <div class="image-container">
           <a target="_blank" href="img/portrait.jpg">
               <img src="img/portrait.jpg" alt="portrait">
           </a>
           <!-- <div class="desc">Add a description here</div> -->
       
    </div>
      <div class="image-container">
           <a target="_blank" href="img/flowers2.jpg">
               <img src="img/flowers2.jpg" alt="flowers2">
           </a>
           <!-- <div class="desc">Add a description here</div> -->
       
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do mind cropped images or are you trying to present images to its fullest width or height without cropping?

Comment: I just corrected my post to mention this. I don't mind if it is cropped. Just as long as it fills the width, height and is centered.

Comment: `object-position: 50% 50%` to center and `object-fit:cover` https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/ remove all of those styles on img otherwise it won't be effective.

Comment: That's an interesting method however for some reason it's not working at all for me. I removed the other styles as you mentioned and replaced them with the object-position and object-fit but all that happened was they blew up to full size images within the div and only showed the top left corner. They wouldn't position differently when I try manipulate the object-position...

Comment: Nevermind I got it working with that method, just took a little fiddling around. Any idea how to center my entire gallery? It's currently going from left to right and when I make the browser window big it is not centered.

Comment: Sure, see my answer. BTW, glad you got it working, I neglected the addition of a relative measurement of dimensions, it's added to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`object-fit` and `object-position`**](https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/) are CSS properties specialized in the behavior of **[replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)** like `<img>` and `<video>`. Applied like so:

```
div.image-container img {
  /* Added */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Added */
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  /* Added */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

This particular ruleset will render the `<img>` so that it will fill its parent container edge to edge without distortion *but* cropping will happen should the dimensions of the parent not coincide with the image's AR (Aspect Ratio).

To center a series of elements, **[`display:flex` and `justify-content:center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)** on the parent should suffice:

```
.gallery-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  /* Added */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

### Demo

```css
.gallery-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  /* Added */
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 23%;
}

div.image-container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.image-container img {
  /* Added */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Added */
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  /* Added */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container">

  <div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="img/60.jpg">
      <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/plumeria.jpg" alt="flowers">
    </a>
    <!-- <div class="desc">Add a description here
                  
               </div> -->
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="img/portrait.jpg">
      <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/plumeria.jpg" alt="portrait">
    </a>
    <!-- <div class="desc">Add a description here</div> -->

  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <a target="_blank" href="img/flowers2.jpg">
      <img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/plumeria.jpg" alt="flowers2">
    </a>
    <!-- <div class="desc">Add a description here</div> -->

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I also added `flex-wrap: wrap` to it for responsiveness.

Comment: That's great, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
div.image-container img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
    width:100%;
```

}